# MSTest ClassInitialize once for entire class

Tags: unit-testing, mstest

ClassInitialize seems to be getting called for every test. I guess it is because a new class is actually created for every test.

Why? Every other framework doesn't do this!

Anyways...  I need to execute one method (not static) on the class. I also need to execute all the test methods within the same instance of the class.

Am I up a creek without a paddle?

Comment: some reason you can't just call one, then call the other?

Comment: All within one test? I could do that, but I would loose immediate visibility into which tests failed. One test called "AllTests"?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`ClassInitialize` is called once by MSTest before any of the `TestMethod`s are invoked, see remarks [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.classinitializeattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). `TestInitialize` is called once before each test method. MSTest creates a new instance of the test class for each `TestMethod` call. This is why `ClassInitialize` is a static method.

> I need to execute one method (not static) on the class. I also need to execute all the test methods within the same instance of the class.

Do you mean you need to execute one method on the `TestClass` or the class under test (the class you are actually testing)?

In either case, you can have a static member in the `TestClass` and initialize it once in `ClassInitialize`. It will be created only once and exist for the lifetime of your tests. You can invoke a method on it only once. You can then use this single instance in each of your test methods.

One thing to be aware of is that MSTest may interleave tests from different classes. So if you have any global mutable state which is accessed from more than one `ClassInitialize` (or test for that matter), unpredictable things might happen. For that reason, statics are best avoided.

The requirement that all methods must be executed on the same instance is quite unusual. Perhaps there is a way to refactor your code to eliminate this constraint?